# Simple way to format date

Tags: perl, datetime

I wrote a perl script to get datetime.
It do work but I do wonder if there any easier way to format date as output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;

my $dt          = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );
$myTimeStamp    = $dt->subtract( days => 1 );
$myYear         = $myTimeStamp->year;
$myMonth        = $myTimeStamp->month;
if ( length( $myMonth ) == 1 ) {
    $myMonth = "0$myMonth";
}
$myDay          = $myTimeStamp->day;
if ( length( $myDay ) == 1 ) {
    $myDay = "0$myDay";
}
$myHour         = $myTimeStamp->hour;
if ( length( $myHour ) == 1 ) {
    $myHour = "0$myHour";
}
#$myDir          = "/var/tmp/logs/$myYear/$myMonth/$myYear$myMonth-";

print "--> $myYear $myMonth $myDay $myHour\n";
# --> 2012 02 28 02
exit 0;
```

Comment: You have a DateTime object in $myTimeStamp. A DateTime object has a `strftime` method. Use it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) provides the `format_cldr` method for this:

```
use DateTime;

my $myTimeStamp = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 1 );

printf "--> %s\n", $myTimeStamp->format_cldr('yyyy MM dd HH');
# --> 2012 02 28 02
```

Comment: [also](http://p3rl.org/DateTime#strftime-Patterns): `$myTimeStamp->strftime('%Y %m %d %H')`

Answer (score 7):

Sure, use [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module:

> The POSIX module permits you to access all (or nearly all) the
>   standard POSIX 1003.1 identifiers.

Example:

```
use POSIX;
print POSIX::strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', localtime());
```

Comment: Pray POSIX my fellow brothers and sisters ! I would have a slight preference for the `strftime` solution as being "part" of Perl Core.

Comment: @Ouki, this points up one of the issues with providing generic Perl answers. In a mature enough codebase, a programmer has all sorts of wiring idioms--not necessarily on CPAN. To give a completely truthful answer on how I would do something, requires all sorts of minimal importation of my toolset of programming idiom. If I want a standard format for a date, it might be a putoff to pass the same format at every call. But when a date is converted to a string, `POSIX::strftime` is how the date becomes string.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all *always* `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the start of your program and declare all your variables close to their first use. This applies especially if you are seeking help as it will find a lot of simple errors that aren't immediately obvious.

It is best to use `printf` if you want to zero-pad any output. There is also no need to extract the date fields to separate variables. Is the output you have shown the one you ultimately want? This program does the same thing as the code you have posted.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $myTimeStamp = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 1 );
printf "--> %04d %02d %02d %02d\n", map $myTimeStamp->$_, qw/year month day hour/;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
--> 2012 02 28 12
```

Comment: I need to extract the date fields later to build dir path. `printf` may not work out.

Answer (score 1):

For re-formatting dates, as noted, there is the [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) core module.  You would be remiss not to look at the core module  [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece-1.20/Piece.pm) too, which not only delivers `strftime()` but also `strptime()` to provide very flexible date/time parsing.  `Time::Piece` appeared in Perl core in 5.9.5.