# how to change 1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z date format to 17-May-2013 in perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way to format date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497960/simple-way-to-format-date)

how to change "1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z" date format to 17-May-2013 in perl

Need help on it. Thank you very much

Comment: ...umm. Is the date difference of almost 17 years of relevance to your question? Also if you "need help on it" you'll have to show which part you need help on. Show some code please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

```
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339 qw( );
my $format = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new();
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z');
say $dt->strftime('%d-%b-%Y');  # 29-Aug-1996
```

[DateTime::Format::RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::RFC3339)

---

A lighter solution:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my ($y, $m, $d) = '1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z' =~ /^(....)-(..)-(..)/s;
say strftime('%d-%b-%Y', 0,0,0, $d,$m-1,$y-1900);  # 29-Aug-1996
```

Comment: Add `$dt->add(days => 6105)` to go to May 17th 2013.

Comment: @simbabque, He never said "1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z" should give "17-May-2013". `"1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z"` is the format, not the input.

Comment: @ikegami, was right.. I only need the format..thanks all now i testing on it..But facing this error  "Can't find string terminator "EOP" anywhere before EOF at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/List/MoreUtils.pm line 1." anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: user1462973, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this unrelated problem.

Comment: between i facing below error. I have using base.pm from cpan. anyone know how to solve it ?
Missing right curly or square bracket at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm line 1, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm line 1, at EOF

Comment: `cpan DateTime::Locale::Base`?

Comment: Added a lighter solution to my answer.

Comment: light solution work !.Thanks ikegami